# Uniqueness for ODE systems, what do we need besides Lipschitz?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE system I'm interested is: 
$$ x^\prime(t)= (1-x(t))/y(t)$$
$$ y^\prime(t)=(1-y(t))/x(t)$$ with initial condition
$$ (x(0),y(0))=(1,1).$$

Let $F(x,y)=((1-x)/y, (1-y)/x)$ then the Jacobian of $F$ is 
$$ JF=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\partial_x F_1 & \partial_y F_1 \\\partial_x F_2& \partial_y F_2 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}-\frac{1}{y} & -\frac{1-x}{y^2} \\ -\frac{1}{x} & -\frac{1-y}{x^2} \end{array}\right), $$

which is continuous and bounded in some convex neighborhood of $(1,1)$, say the ball with radius 1/2 and center on $(1,1)$, $D=B_{1/2}(1,1)$. Hence, $F$ is uniformly Lipschitz on $D$. Accordingly to the [book](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/1988) that I'm using, this should be enough to guarantee the uniqueness of the solution of the ODE system. But if we use the fact this is an autonomous system, we can write it as:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}y=\frac{(1-y)y}{(1-x)x}$$
and any of its infinite solutions, $y=\frac{x}{1-c+cx}$, satisfies the initial condition $x=1$, $y=1$.

I'm probably missing something very trivial but I can't see what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right side of your equation for $dy/dx$ is undefined when $x=1$, so it's not quite true to say $y = x/(1-c+cx)$ is a a solution of this differential equation with initial condition $x=1,y=1$.  The system will have trajectories 
along these curves, but they will not reach $x=1,y=1$ at any finite time, only
in a limit as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: So in the original system, there is indeed an unique solution? $x(t)=1$ and $y(t)=1$? Do I know you from Maple primes? Toda raba!

Comment: Yes, yes and yes.